# Python: Spyder crashed and doesn't open anymore

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I use Spyder to run my python codes in my Mac OS x.
It happens that spyder just crashed, and since them it doesn't open anymore.
When I try to open it directly from ~/anaconda/bin, the following error msg appears:
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3h53.png)

after I click in ok, I get back the lines of error:

```
    [Julias-MBP-3:~/anaconda/bin] juliaroquette% ./spyder
2017-06-19 18:24:06.479 python[713:16813] modalSession has been exited prematurely - check for a reentrant call to endModalSession:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3011, in main
    mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 2913, in run_spyder
    main.setup()
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 784, in setup
    from spyder.plugins.help import Help
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/plugins/help.py", line 33, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.help.sphinxify import (CSS_PATH, generate_context,
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/help/sphinxify.py", line 29, in <module>
    from docutils.utils import SystemMessage as SystemMessage
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import docutils.io
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/io.py", line 18, in <module>
    from docutils.utils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/error_reporting.py", line 47, in <module>
    locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 564, in getlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Users/juliaroquette/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 477, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

I tried to do what the error msg suggest, and use the option --reset, but the same error still exist after that.

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known that the MacPorts version of Spyder is raising this error:

ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

which doesn’t let it start correctly.

To fix it you will have to set these environment variables in your .profile (or .bashrc) manually:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```